# The Cursed Gun in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I just played an optional mission in Borderlands 2 called The Bane and as the mission reward I got a cursed gun called as the Bane itself. The Bane turned out to be an SMG and since it is cursed(my opinion), it immensely reduces my movement speed whenever I wield it. It also got poor accuracy and the only advantage I can see is its high damage potential.

So I thought about selling it but I just needed advice from somebody who already beat this game.

1) Should I sell the gun?

2) Do the drawbacks outweigh the advantage(s)?

3) Will it become useful later in the game?

I'm playing as Zero, the Assassin and because of this I haven't quite used SMG-s. So if there are some plus points I'm not seeing in this cursed gun, please let me know about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bane is almost completely useless, as well as being incredibly annoying.

If you can handle the annoying sound effects, it can be useful when playing as Anarchy-spec Gaige, or when you want to unload a lot of damage into a large enemy at point blank range. Besides that there's no reason to keep it.

Comment: Anarchy further reduces accuracy, how are you supposed to atleast hold the gun?

Comment: @slayerdiangelo You use Close Enough and rely on riccochets.

Answer (score 4):

It can be very useful during fight-for-your-life time because you can't move very quickly anyway. The accuracy starts off pretty good, and generally improves the more shots you fire (since it's a Hyperion SMG).
[Wiki](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Bane)